# Magento 1.9.2.4 production mode

Tags: magento-1.9

Does magento 1.9.x has a production mode? And if yes how do i set Magento 1.9.2.4 to production mode?

I managed to do it for 2.x but i don't see how to do it for 1.9.x :(

Thank you!

Comment: There is not such mode in Magento 1.9.x.

Comment: Thank you @PurushotamSharma, for your answer! I should've asked earlier :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "proudction mode" in Magento 1.

You can only enable "developer mode" for displaying error reports and exceptions on frontend.

Therefor you can add this to your .htacces:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Comment: Okay so basically I've lost an entire day trying to figure this out and the answer was so simple :D thank you! :D